# If $A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ and $B\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ inconsistent, then $(A+B)\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ inconsistent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The matrices $A$ and $B$ are of $n \times m$. Suppose there is a $\vec{b}$ such that both $A\vec{x}=B\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ have infinitely many solutions. Is it true that $(A+B)\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ also has infinitely many solutions?

I tried to prove this by considering $A\vec{x}=B\vec{x}=\vec{b}$. So $(A+B)\frac{\vec{x}}{2}=\vec{b}$. Let $\vec{y}=\frac{\vec{x}}{2}$, then $(A+B)\vec{y}=\vec{b}$. Since $\vec{y} \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\vec{x}$ has many solutions, $\vec{y}$ also has infinitely many solutions. Hence, it is true that $(A+B)\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ also has infinitely many solutions.

So far, has what I have done proved the claim that $(A+B)\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ also has infinitely many solutions?

Now, if I take it a little further to make the problem as suppose there is a $\vec{b}$ such that both $A\vec{x}=\vec{b}=B\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ are inconsistent. Is it true that $(A+B)\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ is also inconsistent?

I wanted to do the same as the previous one but it doesn't sound very right to still say $A\vec{x}=B\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ since the system isn't consistent and so there isn't an $\vec{x}$ to make the equation well-defined. If this is the case, what else can I do to test if the claim is true or false?

Comment: The proof in the second paragraph is wrong. We know that infinitely many $x$ exist with $Ax = b$, and infinitely many $z$ exist with $Bz = b$. But that doesnt means that the intersection of these $x$s and $z$s (the solutions to $Ax = Bx = b$) is also infinite. (As in Yuval's example below, it could be that $\{x: Ax=b\} \cap \{z: Bz=b\} = \{0\}$ so $|\{x: Ax=b\} \cap \{z: Bz=b\}| < \infty$.)

Comment: Consider $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, $B = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, $b = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: Wouldn't it be $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
5
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\ 
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
5
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
5
\end{bmatrix}$ $$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
5
\end{bmatrix} \neq \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\ 
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
5
\end{bmatrix}$$
Wouldn't the $\vec{x}$ need to be a common one that satisfies the 2 equations?

Comment: @ThijsLaarhoven: So when it says $A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ and $B\vec{x}=\vec{b}$, it doesn't mean that when the equations are are evaluated, the $\vec{x}$ must be the same value in the 2 equations?

Comment: @xEnOn: If the statement is "Suppose there is a $b$ such that both $Ax=b$ and $Bx=b$ have infinitely many solutions." as above, then that should be interpreted as that the (seperate) sets of solutions to $Ax = b$ and $Bx = b$ are both infinite.

Comment: @ThijsLaarhoven: Would the proof I attempted still be wrong if the set of solutions $\vec{x}$ is interpreted as the same set? And curiously, how would the problem be phrased if it was intended to be interpreted as the same set of solutions?

Comment: @xEnOn: Yes, then your proof should work (although I don't understand the "$y \in \mathbb{R}$", and "$\vec{x}$ has many solutions" is not what you meant). And I would phrase it something like "Suppose there is a $b$ such that $Ax = Bx = b$ has infinitely many solutions."

Comment: @ThijsLaarhoven: Thanks. I wrote the part that $\vec{x}$ has many solutions because I wasn't sure if $\vec{y}$ will give the idea that it was inherited from $\vec{x}$ and has many possible solutions to the equations too. I updated my question such that the $\vec{x}$ should be treated as the same set in both equations because it is clear that if $\vec{x}$ is treated as separate sets, addition between the matrices cannot determine if it will still be linearly independent or inconsistent.

Comment: @xEnOn: What you said is still not what think you are saying. Your correction still reads "$Ax=b$ and $Bx=b$ each have infinitely many solutions", but does not require the same specific solutions to satisfy both equations. Rather, you want to say something like "Suppose that $b$ is such that $Ax=b$ and $Bx=b$ have infinitely many solutions **in common**..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments, it seems that your first problem is supposed to read something like:

> Suppose $A$ and $B$ are matrices, and $\vec{b}$ is such that the systems of linear equations $A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ and $B\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ have infinitely many solutions **in common.** Is it true that $(A+B)\vec{t}=\vec{b}$ has infinitely many solutions?

If that's the case, then your argument works: for each common solution $\vec{x}$ to the original two systems, $\frac{1}{2}\vec x$ is a solution to $(A+B)\vec{x}=\vec{b}$; since $\frac{1}{2}\vec{x} = \frac{1}{2}\vec{x'}$ if and only if $\vec{x}=\vec{x'}$, it follows that the latter system has infinitely many solutions as well.

But you need the solutions to be **common solutions**, as Yuval's example shows.

The second question is false in two interpretations:

> Suppose $A$ and $B$ are matrices, and $\vec{b}$ is such that the systems of linear equations $A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ and $B\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ have no solutions in common. Is it true that $(A+B)\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ has no solutions?

and

> Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are matrices, and $\vec{b}$ is such that the systems of linear equations $A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ and $B\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ each has no solutions. Is it true that $(A+B)\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ has no solutions?

This is false; note that any pair of matrices $A$ and $B$ and vector $\vec{b}$ that satisfy the second statement will also satisfy the first, so it suffices to find a counterexample to the second statement. The following works:
$$A = \left(\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&0\end{array}\right),\quad B=\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&0\\0&1\end{array}\right),\quad \vec{b}=\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\1\end{array}\right).$$

Suppose now we tweak it a bit, perhaps; how about the following?

> Suppose $A$ and $B$ are matrices, and $\vec{b}$ is such that $A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ and $B\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ each has solutions, but there are no solutions in common to both systems. Is it true that $(A+B)\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ has no solutions?

This is still not true. Take
$$A=\left(\begin{array}{crc}
1&-1&0\\
0&0&1
\end{array}\right),\quad 
B=\left(\begin{array}{ccr}
1&0&0\\
0&1&-1
\end{array}\right),\quad
\vec{b}=\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\1\end{array}\right).$$
Then $A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ has solutions: $\vec{x}=(1,0,1)^T$ is a solution. $B\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ also has solutions: $\vec{x}=(1,1,0)^T$ is a solution.

But $A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ and $B\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ have no solutions in common: if $\vec{x}=(x,y,z)^T$ were a solution, then you would need $x-y=1$, $z=1$, $x=1$, and $y-z=1$. But from $x=z=1$ and $x-y=0$, we get $y=0$; and from $z=1$ and $y-z=1$ we get $y=2$.

However,
$$(A+B)\vec{x} = \left(\begin{array}{rrr}2 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right)\vec{x} = \left(\begin{array}{c}1\\1\end{array}\right)$$
*does* have solutions: $(1,1,z)^T$ is a solution for all $z$.